# Win-Lose-Tie Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I've always struggled comprehending combinatorics problems and encountered this real-life scenario that was giving me trouble. Appreciate a simple walkthrough for how to approach it:

In a 3-day tournament between 8 individuals, where the format is given as:

Day 1: one match of 4 vs 4
Day 2: two matches of 2 vs 2
Day 3: four matches of 1 vs 1

How do you calculate all possible win-loss-tie scenarios for the entire 3 days?
For example, this is easily done for just day 1 alone:

1-0-0
0-1-0
0-0-1

0-0-0 is not a valid result as there must always either be a winner/loser or a tie

So there are 3 possible scenarios for day 1. How do I determine the total sum of outcomes for all three days? Order does not matter and the match outcomes are not otherwise related. Thank you!

Comment: There are a total of $(1 + 2 + 4)$ matches.  Each match has $3$ possible outcomes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sorry if I wasn't clear but I'm looking for how to calculate all possible outcomes of all three days. So one example outcome would be: day 1: Team 1 beats Team 2 .... day 2: Team 1 beats Team 2 and Team 3 ties Team 4 .... day 3: 1 beats 2, 4 beats 3, 5 and 6 tie, and 7 beats 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are $(1 + 2 + 4) = 7$ matches, and each match has $3$ possible outcomes, there are $3^7$ distinct results possible.

One way of describing this list is as follows: 
Index the matches $\{0,1,2,\cdots,6\}$. 
For Match $k$, where $k \in \{0,1,\cdots,6\}$, 
arbitrarily choose one of the two competing sides in Match $k$, 
and designate this chosen side as the *favorite*.

Then, for each of the $3$ possible outcomes for Match $k$,
assign the values $0,1,2$ depending on
whether the underdog won, the favorite won, or it was a tie, respectively.

Then, you will have that each of the distinct $3^7$ outcomes may be expressed as a **zero filled, 7-digit, base 3 number.**

For example, the base $3$ number of $1201201_{\text{base} ~3}$ 
would represent that :

- the favorite won match $0$.
- the underdog won match $1$.
- match $2$ ended in a tie.
- the favorite won match $3$.
- the underdog won match $4$.
- match $5$ ended in a tie.
- the favorite won match $6$.

---

> How do I determine the total sum of outcomes for all three days?

It is unclear what you are asking here.  If you are asking for the total number of distinct outcomes, then, as discussed, that number is $3^7.$  If you are instead asking for some sort of summation of these $3^7$ outcomes, then it depends on what values you are using for each of the $3$ outcomes of underdog winning, favorite winning, or tie.

Suppose that the symbols that you referred to are adopted.  Namely, for each match the possible outcomes are

- $1-0-0$
- $0-1-0$
- $0-0-1$

Then, the **sum** of the $3$ outcomes, for one specific match might be interpreted as:

- $1-1-1$.

If this is what you are looking for, then, since there are $7$ matches total, the **sum** of all of the possible outcomes of all of the $7$ matches would be:

- $7-7-7$.

Here, I am not really clear on what you intend by the word **sum**.

Comment: Perfect thanks! The first part of your response was what I was looking for. By "total sum of outcomes" I simply meant determining the number of distinct results possible.